# unix_timestamp producing null values in spark sql and writing null values to table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using unix_timestamp in my spark sql and running through spark scala but if i change the hardcoded value to below 3 hours i am getting null values but it works fine in hive terminal.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('03/08/2020 03:00:00','MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

output : `2020-03-08`

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('03/08/2020 02:59:59','MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

output : `null`

Answer (score 1):

In some countries the clocks go forward for 1 hour at 2AM of 8th March 2020 due to daylight saving time (summer time). The clock changed from 2AM to 3AM and the intermediate times do not exist on 8th March 2020. That's why if you attempt to convert a non-existent time to unix_time, you got null.

You might get a result in Hive if you have a different timezone setting. To set the timezone in Spark, use `set spark.sql.session.timeZone = UTC;`, for example.

Comment: How can i resolve this in my query?